# CMD.exe and Powershell.exe cannot generate ssh keys using ssh-keygen

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, cmd, access-denied

Hope you can help me out here. I've been playing around with some SSH authentication. I have no idea why this is happening, but now when I run a simple `ssh-keygen` command I get a response saying `Access is denied.` in addition to a pop-up that reads "This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher".

I then tried running the ssh-keygen command in Powershell (as admin and as regular user) and got the following:

```
Program 'ssh-keygen.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.At
line:1 char:1
+ ssh-keygen
+ ~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ ssh-keygen
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

However, using ssh -V shows that it is installed:

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

I can still SSH fine into other devices, if that's of any relevant.

Any help would be very much appreciated here!

Comment: `ssh-keygen.exe` is clearly _present_, but presumably _corrupted_ (There may also be _multiple_ copies). Run `Get-Command -All ssh-keygen.exe | Get-Item` to make sure no zero-byte files by that name are in your `$env:PATH`.

Comment: @KJ: 64-bit PowerShell instances can invoke 32-bit executables and vice versa - and I'm not sure 16-bit executables are still around.

Comment: @KJ, I don't think there's agreement here: my point was that calling a valid 32-bit or 64-bit executable should work just fine, both from a 32-bit and a 64-bit PowerShell session. The differing error messages seem to stem from different _invocation methods_.

Comment: ssh.exe and ssh-keygen.exe are different tools, so obviously if there are any probleems with ssh-keygen then ssh still runs as normal. Try running `sfc /scannow` to fix some possible problems